# Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-backup/Model/Db.php on line 156

Tags: error, magento-2.1, backup

When i tried to start a DB backup via:

```
php bin/magento setup:backup --db
```

I got this error:

```
Enabling maintenance mode
DB backup is starting...
Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-backup/Model/Db.php on line 156
Disabling maintenance mode
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /var/www/magento/vendor/magentframework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3774 in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/var/www/magent...', 3774, Array)
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3774): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
```

My Magento version: 2.1.1

It's the same via the web interface.

Comment: Could you share with us what your PHP version is? That could be helpful

Comment: PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 4):

So just came across this error myself, thought I might mention it for those who may come across this in future (since it does block updates).

Looks like the db dump crashed while trying to add rows for or around "importexport_importdata" table

A quick glance it looks like a small issue with not checking for a non-zero denominator.

The code/file in question is: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Backup/Model/Db.php#L156

I managed to fix the issue by overriding/localing the file and modifying the line

```
$limit = floor(self::BUFFER_LENGTH / $tableStatus->getAvgRowLength());
```

to

```
$limit = floor(self::BUFFER_LENGTH / max($tableStatus->getAvgRowLength(), 1));
```

And keeping the rest intact